# Error if nothing is set in form PHP

Tags: php, forms, null, isset, strpos

I've been wondering how to avoid an error when a page is first loaded, and it holds a form that a function/operation requires. 
**Problem:** I'm getting an error, because the form has not been submitted and the variables inside are needed to run the rest of the script.

Bear with my wording, I'm obv a beginner.

But let's take what I'm working with for example, It's all on the same page.

IF this is the first time my page has been loaded and I do not enter anything into my form, i get an Unidentified Index: "$variable" that I use for my form.

Right now I'm running through a simple strpos tutorial that I basically turned into a search engine bought at walmart.

**Index.php**

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Project # </title>
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
</form>

<?php
$article = " Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.";

echo $article;

$search = $_POST['search'];

if(!isset($_SERVER['submit'])){

    if(strpos($article, $search) !== false){

echo "<br> We found what you were looking for.. ";


    }
    else{

        echo " <br> nope, remember we probably need exact matches here.";
    }

}
else {
    echo "<br> form is not set ";
}
?>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST["search"]` will initially not exist, so you need to check if `$_POST["search"]` is set.

```
$article = " Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.";

echo $article;

if(isset($_POST["search"])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    if(!isset($_SERVER['submit'])){

        if(strpos($article, $search) !== false){
            echo "<br> We found what you were looking for.. ";
        }else{
            echo " nope, remember we probably need exact matches here.";
        }
    }else {
        echo "<br> we couldn't find it ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if `$_POST` is empty it exists. *so you need to check if $_POST["search"] is set.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check is user has actually provided some sort of input and not just submitted a form without typing anything. HTML itself allows you to use its *[required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)* function to automatically give the user an error if the field is empty.

Alternatively you can use *[Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)* to make it a bit more fancier an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Js2C/). How ever both the above methods can be bypassed so if all of that fails then you *need* to ensure you have some sort of "main" defense which the user can't mess with, that's when PHP comes in to play. As it is a sever side language the user can't mess with it. You can do the following to ensure fields are completed.

```
if(!isset($_POST['someField']) || empty($_POST['someField'])) {
    // Error message, as the field is empty
} else {
    // Sanitize user input or do other checks.
}
```

The "!" before the [isset();](https://www.php.net/isset) just reverses it the function, so isset(); checks if the value IS SET where as the "!" says if IT IS NOT SET. As for the "||" that is simply the PHP operator for OR so we are checking if field IS NOT SET OR if it is empty.

If you use all the above then from the users perspective it will make it quite clear that the site wants a certain field to filled in.

**Edit**

You empty(); does not check for spaces so use this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['someField']) || empty(trim($_POST['someField']))) {
    // Some error message
} else {
   // Fields not empty!
}
```